# Replace IDs that are stored as json in varchar columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have a pretty big table ~ 20 million rows in a SQL server 2008R2 database that contains a VARCHAR(MAX) column with json data in it. The json-data points out IDs in other tables.

I have received a task to consolidate 3 databases into 1 single database and since the IDs are BIGINT identities it is impossible to recreate them with the same ID as in the old DB.

My question is:
How do i migrate the json-data to point out the correct new IDs in the shortest amount of execution time? I have created all rows in the new database to also contain the ID of the row in the old DBs so I have no problem with that. But i do not find a way to extract the actual IDs from the varchar and replace them.

Example json:

> [{"TriggerCriteriaID":960,"Values":{"LatestDepositValue":1000.0000,"TransactionFeedID":331449169,"TriggerFinishedDate":"2015-07-25T21:41:22"}},{"TriggerCriteriaID":961,"Values":{"LatestDepositValue":1200.0000,"ActionFeedID":312,"TriggerFinishedDate":"2015-07-25T21:41:22"}}]

It is the following entities that have new IDs that needs replacement:

- TriggerCriteriaID (May exist multiple times in the json)
- TransactionFeedID
- ActionFeedID

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, removing json from the equation entirely and storing its content in appropriate normalised tables is the best way to go.

Comment: Agreed but that would require the dev team to change its product which is not possible at the moment. It need to be a migration only.

Comment: You could try to preserve the ID:s as they are when you insert them into the new tables. Use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <your table> ON ... your insert ... SET IDENTITY_INSERT <your table> OFF` for that

Comment: Thanks, but not possible since there are 3 databases migrated into 1. So IDs are not unique.

Comment: @FredrikR shouldn't be a problem if they are in separate tables? Are you sure you're not mixing up the term *database* with *table*

Comment: Or are you merging tables aswell?

Comment: Nope, for example the table TriggerCriteria in DB1 and DB2 are merged into the same table TriggerCriteria in DB3. So the entities can not keep their old IDs.

Comment: I would go with this approach: 
1. **Get the old ID** from the JSON
2. Lookup the old DB and **extract the business key**
3. Lookup the new DB with the business key and **extract the new ID**
4. **Replace the old ID** in the JSON **with the new ID**